# restore specific database from mysql full .sql backup

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a full back up from my all mysql databases, the problem is that my backup contain default **mysql**, **performance_schema** and **information_schema** databases that prevent me from restoring my backup.

the question is how i cant remove this default databases from my full backup?
i try to edit .sql backup file and delete create and insert for this database, but its make some problem on miss deleting injections.

is there a visual software that i open my .sql file with that and it show me a  databases and the tables and i select some database to delet them ..?????!!!

please help me, my databases are very important ...

**I want something to virtualize my databases and i delete unwanted database from it and save as the result  **

Answer (score 0):

What about doing the following steps:

1. rename default databases in your .sql files
2. restore your backup
3. delete restored renamed databases